# Controller action does not display errors and I cannot see whats wrong

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller

I cannot see why my errors aren’t displaying from the below code. I have a restaurant 1 to many with reviews with both belonging to users (devise model). When a user posts a review an AJAx post request is made with the callback displaying the new review object on page. There review controller create action has a conditional where if restaurants.reviews can find a review with the user_id or current_user it gives a flash error notice and redirects_to /restaurants. All is seemingly fine, review not created if current_user already has a review on the restaurant, and no errors displayed, however the error is not renderred, despite server log stating that it has:

```
Rendered restaurants/_review_errors_form.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered restaurants/index.html.erb within layouts/application (20.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 86.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

Here is my reviews_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @review = @restaurant.reviews.new(params[:review].permit(:thoughts, :rating))

    if @restaurant.reviews.find_by user_id: current_user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You already reviewed this restaurant!" 
      redirect_to '/restaurants'
    else
      @review.user = current_user
      @review.save 
      render 'create', content_type: :json
    end
  end
```

Here is my restaurants.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.new_review').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var reviewList = $(this).siblings('ul');
    var currentRestaurant = $(this).parent();

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(review){
      // if(review)
        var newReview = Mustache.render($('#review_template').html(), review);
        reviewList.append(newReview);

        currentRestaurant.find('.review_count').text(review.restaurant.review_count)
        currentRestaurant.find('.average_rating_number').text(review.restaurant.average_rating);
        currentRestaurant.find('.average_rating_stars').text(review.restaurant.average_rating_stars);
    }, 'json' );
  });
});
```

Application.html.erb does display errors:

```
<%= notice %>
<%= alert %>
```

_review_errors partial all written fine:

```
<% if @review.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@review.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this review from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @review.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have been playing around with lots of different syntax over last few days to better understand this and to try to get things working as I’m intending, and I have seem the errors being rendered fine with some configurations, but for the life of me I can;t get back there now. It’s something to do with the controller syntax I think. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using AJAX to make the call to your `create` action, and in your `$.post` function you're configuring it to receive `'json'` therefore, you can only receive `json` from the `create` action. So, you can't do a `redirect_to` in that action. Instead, you must return the error as `json` and process that response in your `$.post` function.

The reason you're not seeing anything except in the server log is because the `$.post` function will ignore the response because it's not `json`. It doesn't know what to do with it so it silently fails.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes on this one Diego. I guess that i need to change the 'Content-Type' of the response header to application/json, using syntax something like:"Content-type", "application/json". Can you advise as to how exactly i should do this? Thanks again for helping a newbie with this.